# Thread count increasing when clients connect to TIdTCPServer

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10, delphi-10.1-berlin, tcpserver

I have a 64-bit server application created using Delphi 10.1, and in this app I have a `TIdTCPServer` component.

When a client connects, the thread count increases, and when the client disconnects, the thread count is not reducing. This problem occurs on a Windows Server machine. I'm not handling any code in the `OnConnect` and `OnDisconnect` events. Below is my `OnExecute` method:

```
  try
      if not AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
      begin
        AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.ExtractToBytes(ReceivedIDBytes.PointerMessage.tyTIDBytes) ;
        ReceivedIDBytes.ClientSocket := AContext.Connection;
        MessageProcessorThread.ProcessMessageQueue.Enqueue(ReceivedIDBytes);
        IndySleep(50);
      end;
      IndySleep(5);
  except
  end;
```

Shall I use `Application.ProcessMessages()` to resolve this issue?

Because of the thread count increases, I need to restart the Server application regularly.

Answer (score 5):

Don't swallow exceptions! Indy uses exceptions to report things like socket disconnects/errors (`EIdConnClosedGracefully`, `EIdSocketError`, etc).  `TIdTCPServer` internally handles uncaught exceptions raised by its event handlers to know when to cleanup the threads that manage the accepted sockets.  By swallowing exceptions, you are preventing `TIdTCPServer` from doing that cleanup properly.

If you need to catch exceptions for whatever reason (cleanup, logging, etc <sup>1</sup>), you should re-raise any exception that is derived from `EIdException`, at least. Let `TIdTCPServer` handle Indy-generated exceptions, especially ones that occur due to socket disconnection.

<sup>1: consider using the `TIdTCPServer.OnException` event instead for that.</sup>

```pascal
try
  if not AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
  begin
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.ExtractToBytes(ReceivedIDBytes.PointerMessage.tyTIDBytes);
    ReceivedIDBytes.ClientSocket := AContext.Connection;
    MessageProcessorThread.ProcessMessageQueue.Enqueue(ReceivedIDBytes);
    IndySleep(50);
  end;
  IndySleep(5);
except
  on E: Exception do
  begin
    ...
    if E is EIdException then
      raise; // <-- add this!
  end;
end;
```

I would also suggest getting rid of the `IndySleep()` calls, too. You don't actually need them, let Indy do the sleeping for you while waiting for new data to arrive:

```pascal
try
  if AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
  begin
    // the next call sleeps until data arrives or the specified timeout elapses...
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(55);
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.CheckForDisconnect;
    if AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then Exit:
  end;
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.ExtractToBytes(ReceivedIDBytes.PointerMessage.tyTIDBytes);
  ReceivedIDBytes.ClientSocket := AContext.Connection;
  MessageProcessorThread.ProcessMessageQueue.Enqueue(ReceivedIDBytes);
except
  on E: Exception do
  begin
    ...
    if E is EIdException then
      raise;
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively, use `TIdIOHandler.ReadBytes()` instead of using `TIdBuffer.ExtractToBytes()` directly:

```pascal
try
  SetLength(ReceivedIDBytes.PointerMessage.tyTIDBytes, 0);
  // the next call sleeps until data arrives or the IOHandler.ReadTimeout elapses...
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadBytes(ReceivedIDBytes.PointerMessage.tyTIDBytes, -1, False);
  if Length(ReceivedIDBytes.PointerMessage.tyTIDBytes) > 0 then
  begin
    ReceivedIDBytes.ClientSocket := AContext.Connection;
    MessageProcessorThread.ProcessMessageQueue.Enqueue(ReceivedIDBytes);
  end;
except
  on E: Exception do
  begin
    ...
    if E is EIdException then
      raise;
  end;
end;
```